# Function for hue/saturation/lightest range slider

Tags: javascript, html

[image]
[image]false -->

```html
   <div id="colorSpec">
                HEX color: 
                 <!-- The user insert the color the div will have-->
                <input id="userColor" type="text"> <br>
                <input id="doitButton" type="button" value="Do it !"> <br>

                 <!-- Range slider to set the opacity-->
                <input id="mySlider"  type= "range" step=".01" min="0" max="1" value=".5">
            </div>
```

```js
   doitButton.addEventListener("click", function(ev){
                //alert("got a click!");
                var textelement= document.getElementById('userColor');
                var hcolor= textelement.value;
                console.log("hcolor is " + hcolor);
                //set the color took from the input "userColor
                colorBox.style.backgroundColor= hcolor;
                });
                mySlider.addEventListener("input",function(ev){
                 //set the opacity
                colorBox.style.opacity=mySlider.value;
                
                })
    }
```

I am using a range input to modify the background color of a div. I am using a javascript function to do so, and I already did it with the opacity of the div, but when I try with saturation, hue and lightest (hsl), it's doesn't have the same output. I was wondering if the reason why is not working it's because I can't use the same structure for the code.
I am going to show you what I did with the opacity range input:

[[image]
Result:

Comment: Why did you not use `<input type="color" ... ` ???

Comment: I am programming on a "starting template", since is an assignmentm they provide us part of the code, which I should not modify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the HSL value as a string. Adding to this, it should be noted that in the DOM it seems that this is always converted back to `rgb()`or `rgba()`. Even when setting the style property string manually, as per the [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color#Specifications).

> If the value is translucent, the computed value will be the `rgba()` corresponding one. If it isn't, it will be the `rgb()` corresponding one. The transparent keyword maps to `rgba(0,0,0,0)`.

```js
update = () => {
  let hsl = `hsl(${mySlider1.value||0}, ${mySlider2.value||0}%,${mySlider3.value||0}%)`;
  colorBox.style.backgroundColor = hsl;
};

mySlider1.addEventListener("input", update);
mySlider2.addEventListener("input", update);
mySlider3.addEventListener("input", update);
update();
```

```css
#colorBox {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="colorSpec">
  <!-- Range slider to set the opacity-->
  <input id="mySlider1" type="range" step="1" min="0" max="260" value="180">
  <input id="mySlider2" type="range" step="1" min="0" max="100" value="50">
  <input id="mySlider3" type="range" step="1" min="0" max="100" value="50">
</div>
<div id="colorBox"></div>
```